# How do I get if directives to read variables from ldap?

Tags: apache, ldap

I am trying to set an SSO request based on specific variables, in a way that multiple users will have the same account.

For example If their first name is Robert then it would try to login as user robert. etc..

I have apache working in every way except the if statement seems to be seeing the variables as null.

here is what i am trying to do, but the if statement fails.

```
<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    ...other auth ldap stuff
    Require ldap-user %{variable-redacted}
    RequestHeader set Name %{env:AUTHORIZE_FirstName}s
</Location>

<If "%{env:AUTHORIZE_FirstName} in { 'Robert', 'John', 'Steve' }">
    RequestHeader set User "Admin"
</If>
<Else>
    RequestHeader set User "User"
</Else>
```

So far everything works. Except the if statement evaluates false. I tried several methods here and i'm pretty sure it sees the variable as (null)

What really confuses me is if i use this:

```
<If "%{variableName} != 'John'">
    RequestHeader set user %{variableName}s
</If>
```

it will actually set the request header to the variable information.
So what is happening? Why does the if statement fail, but the variable works in the failed if statement?!?!

UPDATE: I will leave this question open if some one figures it out. But in the mean time, I have found a way. Since RewriteCond and RewriteRule are handled in order, as expected, I created a solution for them.
First it sets a variable to the "least precise" username, and then if there is more details i can keep adding rules. and my final rewritecond will check if they are an admin, and correct the user. Then finally sets the requestheader based on the user variable. Once a requestheader is set, it needs to be removed to replace it. but variables can be changed over and over. - I have to say, after this, apache will not be my choice if i can avoid it.

Comment: Why? The assumption throughout is that everyone has their own account. Are you looking for *roles?*

Comment: No, everyone shares accounts but under a similar idea of roles. we have countless users, and need to minimize what they see based on location. Anyhow, I found a method that works based on rewritecond and rewriterule. I just didn't want to do it that way because my brain likes if statements better. lol.